# Multiple path relation check in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-traversal

I'm messing around with a Neo4j query. Is it possible to check with Neo4j Cypher language that all relations of "n1" with label "p" have a path to "n6"? See the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that it is possible :

```
MATCH (n6:Node {name:"n6"})
MATCH (n1:Node {name:"n1"})-[r:p]->()
WITH n1, n6, collect(r) as pRels
RETURN ALL(x IN pRels WHERE shortestPath( (n1)-[*]-(n6) ) )
```

This will return true or false

Answer (score 1):

```
// End node
MATCH (n6 {name:"n6"})
// Start node and neighbors
MATCH (n1 {name:"n1"})-[:p]-(n)
// Shortest paths through the neighbor to the end node,
OPTIONAL MATCH p = shortestPath( (n)-[*]-(n6) )
    // which does not pass through the starting node
    WHERE NOT n1 IN nodes(p)
WITH
     size( collect(distinct n) ) as neighborsCount, 
     count(p) as neighborsWithPathCount
RETURN neighborsCount = neighborsWithPathCount AND 
       neighborsWithPathCount > 0
```